# jQuery how to append data at table use input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a table, and I am having some issues. In most normal cases, I have 4 input fields in which I can add some data and send it to the table in my view. But if it so happens that I have more the 4 values, and I need to add more, I have added a button called **"Plus"** which clears previous values from the field, and waits for a user to add new ones.

So the button **"Plus"** adds data to table, but after pressing the button **Send to table** all the data disappears.

Code:

```js
$('.coButton').on('click', function() {
  $('.changeoverTable').show();
  var arrNumber = new Array();
  $(".changeoverTable > tbody").html('');
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(i) {

    arrNumber.push($(this).val());
    if (arrNumber[i]) {
      $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr><td>Data</td><td>' + arrNumber[i] + '</td></tr>');
    }

  })
});


$('.plusButton').on('click', function() {
  var value = $('#opBarcode').val()
  console.log(value);
  $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr><td>Data</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
  $("#opBarcode").val('');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of data"></center>
<center><button class="coButton">Send to table</button></center>
<center><input type="text" id="opBarcode" placeholder="Enter number of layers"><button class="plusButton">Plus</button></center>
<center><button class="coButton">Send to table</button></center>
<center><input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of nest"></center>
<center><button class="coButton">Send to table</button></center>
<center><input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"></center>
<center><button class="coButton">Send to table</button></center>
<table class="changeoverTable hide">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: On a different note, avoid using `<center>`, it's obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: @Armel it's only to present code here

Comment: _“but after pressing the button Send to table all the data disappears”_ - well you are not _keeping_ that data anywhere … You empty the text input next to the Plus button after the latter was clicked, and your Send to table buttons always clear the whole table, and then rebuild it by going through the values of the text fields … If you want to rebuild the whole table all the time, then you need to keep these values added via the Plus button somewhere, so that you can insert them again the next time. Or you need to stop rebuilding the whole table each time to begin with …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.coButton').on('click', function () {
    $('.changeoverTable').show();
    var arrNumber = new Array();
    $(".add").each(function () {
  $(this).remove();
 });
    $('input[type=text]').each(function (i) {

        arrNumber.push($(this).val());
        if (arrNumber[i]) {
  
   if($(".changeoverTable > tbody > tr").hasClass("add_more")) {
    $(".changeoverTable > tbody .add_more").first().before('<tr class="add"><td>Data</td><td>' + arrNumber[i] + '</td></tr>');
   }else{
    $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr class="add"><td>Data</td><td>' + arrNumber[i] + '</td></tr>');
   }
            
        }

    })
});


$('.plusButton').on('click', function () {
    var value = $('#opBarcode').val();
 if(value){
  $(".changeoverTable > tbody").append('<tr class="add_more"><td>Data</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
 }
 
});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <center><input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of data"></center>
            <center><button class="coButton">Send to table</button></center>
            <center><input type="text" id="opBarcode" placeholder="Enter number of layers">
      <button class="plusButton">Plus</button></center>
            <center><button class="coButton">Send to table</button></center>
            <center><input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of nest"></center>
            <center><button class="coButton">Send to table</button></center>
            <center><input type="text" placeholder="Enter number of layers"></center>
            <center><button class="coButton">Send to table</button></center>
        <table class="changeoverTable hide">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">Table</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```js
function appen() {
  var a = $("#mytext").val();
  var b = $("#lastname").val();
  var c = $("#any").val();
  $("#mytable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + c + "</td></tr>");
  $("#mytext").val('');
  $("#lastname").val('');
  $("#any").val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="mytext" />
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
<input type="text" id="any" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="appen()" id="submit" />
<br />
<br />
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>lastname</th>
      <th>anything</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you read description, i can add data to table, and this working, but when i add data to table used button "Plus" data is disappear

Comment: ohh i missed that sorry

Comment: tell me what is the purpose of your plus button?what you exactly want?

Comment: so, for example i have 4 input fields, but at same time i have 7 values, so at input field #2 i can add additional value to table using button Plus

Comment: But if u will check the code, u will see the button Plus add data to table, but when u will press Send to table, this data will disappear

Comment: Hey Please take your array out of button click event i mean initialize it globally so that you can have your old table values as well .

Comment: I try it, but i have loop, which add empty data to array

Comment: then please create a check on the value to be added, if it is null then don't add it to the Global array this will definitely work,Let me try i will be back soon

Comment: Loop add more value the i need so i add this code:   if ($(this).val() != "") {
            arrNumber.push($(this).val());
            console.log(arrNumber);
        } else {
            console.log("Empy data");
        }

Comment: the thing i know is that the problem you are facing is because of your array do not store old value when you add a new input. The real answer that will work is placing your array globally so that click will not initialize it again .Move your array out of the click .Try again i also faced the same problem some time before.

Comment: I try so many method to solve this issues but still now it;s not working

Comment: i have posted a new one . your aim is to add as many as rows to a table right?

Answer (score 1):

Run this in jsfiddle you can add as many rows without using array!

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var myarr = [];
    });
    function appen() {
        var a = $("#mytext").val();
    
        $("#mytable tbody").append("<tr><td>" +a+ "</td></tr>");
        $("#mytext").val('');
        $("#lastname").val('');
        $("#any").val('');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="mytext" />
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="appen()" id="submit" />

<br />
<br />
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```